# Measuring heights of equations for use with \vspace*, rather than using vphantom

Tags: beamer, overlays

Often in beamer I want to produce a build-in. A complicated version is when I want to start with `<expr>` and then build in an underbrace `\underbrace{<expr>}_{foo}`. If the slide is centered vertically, and I do so with `\only<1>{...}` and then `\only<2->{...}`, then I will see a jump in the equation because the *height* of the displayed equation with the `underbrace` is larger.

One solution is to put a `\vphantom{...}` in the `\only<1>{...}`, but this requires that I copy the larger expression (with, say, the underbrace) from `\only<2->{...foo...}` into the first `\only<1>{... \vphantom{foo}...}`. This is a rather ugly solution because my code has just doubled in size, usually.

I'd prefer an approach where I measure heights into the `.aux` and use these in the second compilation (or third, I don't mind) to just use simply `\vspace*{\heightfoo}`.

Any ideas out there?

Here's a MWE:

```
\[
\hat w = \arg\min_{w}
\only<1>{\frac 1 m \sum_{i=1}^{m} f(w) \vphantom{ \underbrace{\frac 1 m \sum_{i=1}^{m} f(w)}_{L(w)}}}%
\only<2->{\underbrace{\frac 1 m \sum_{i=1}^{m} f(w)}_{L(w)}}
\]
```

Comment: Your code is not an MWE.

Comment: I've fixed a typo in the code. MWE now runs (in beamer environment).

Comment: It is still not an MWE. An MWE contains the code that is necessary, so it will compile on it own.

Comment: THis is an MWE: \documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\[
\hat w = \arg\min_{w}
\only<1>{\frac 1 m \sum_{i=1}^{m} f(w) \vphantom{ \underbrace{\frac 1 m \sum_{i=1}^{m} f(w)}_{L(w)}}}%
\only<2->{\underbrace{\frac 1 m \sum_{i=1}^{m} f(w)}_{L(w)}}
\]

\end{frame}

\end{document}

Comment: please always post a complete document not a fragment. Your code doesn't need to double in size to repeat any part of the document `\newcommand\foo{long equation} \foo .. \foo` will use the equation in two contexts

Answer (score 3):

The following code makes `\underbrace` and `\overbrace` overlay-aware and uses `\alt<os>{<default>}{<alternative>}` to print `<default>` on `<os>` and `<alternative>` elsewhere. So, `\underbrace<os>{<stuff>}_{<label>}` sets `\underbrace{<stuff>}_{<label>}` on `<os>` and `\vphantom{\underbrace{<stuff>}_{<label>}}<stuff>` elsewhere (similarly for `\overbrace`).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xparse,letltxmacro}

\LetLtxMacro\oldunderbrace\underbrace
\LetLtxMacro\oldoverbrace\overbrace

\RenewDocumentCommand{\underbrace}{d<> m e{_^}}{%
  \alt<#1>%
    {\oldunderbrace{#2}_{\IfValueT{#3}{#3}}^{\IfValueT{#4}{#4}}}%
    {\vphantom{\oldunderbrace{#2}_{\IfValueT{#3}{#3}}^{\IfValueT{#4}{#4}}}#2}%
}%
\RenewDocumentCommand{\overbrace}{d<> m e{_^}}{%
  \alt<#1>%
    {\oldoverbrace{#2}_{\IfValueT{#3}{#3}}^{\IfValueT{#4}{#4}}}%
    {\vphantom{\oldoverbrace{#2}_{\IfValueT{#3}{#3}}^{\IfValueT{#4}{#4}}}#2}%
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \[
    \hat w = \arg\min_w
      \underbrace<2->{\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i = 1}^{m} f(w)}_{L(w)}
  \]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```